# Error running WSGI application Pythonanywhere Wagtail application

Tags: python, django, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I am running into this problem on pythonanywhere where my webpage won't render. I suspect it is something with the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE but I can't seem to get it to work.

Also tried to use 'Wagtail-Onepage-Portfolio.settings' but did not work either.

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/webconexus/portfolio/portfolio/Wagtail-Onepage-Portfolio'
if path not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'portfolio.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is the `/var/www/www_rafrasenberg_nl_wsgi.py`

```
Error running WSGI application
2019-02-06 14:58:00,884: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
2019-02-06 14:58:00,884:   File "/var/www/www_rafrasenberg_nl_wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2019-02-06 14:58:00,884:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2019-02-06 14:58:00,884: 
2019-02-06 14:58:00,884:   File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-02-06 14:58:00,884:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-02-06 14:58:00,884: 
2019-02-06 14:58:00,885:   File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2019-02-06 14:58:00,885:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2019-02-06 14:58:00,885: 
2019-02-06 14:58:00,885:   File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
2019-02-06 14:58:00,885:     self._setup(name)
2019-02-06 14:58:00,885: 
2019-02-06 14:58:00,885:   File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
2019-02-06 14:58:00,885:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2019-02-06 14:58:00,885: 
2019-02-06 14:58:00,886:   File "/home/webconexus/portfolio/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
2019-02-06 14:58:00,886:     raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
2019-02-06 14:58:00,886: ***************************************************
2019-02-06 14:58:00,886: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2019-02-06 14:58:00,886: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2019-02-06 14:58:00,886: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2019-02-06 14:58:00,886: ***************************************************
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear to me. Your `SECRET_KEY` field (in your application's settings.py file) is empty. You need to provide a value for that setting (Django won't start without it). See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#secret-key) for more.